# Calculate SHA-256 hash and B64 of a file in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, hash, sha256

what is the simplest way to calculate the SHA-256 of a file in JavaScript? (using the File API of W3C)

Once I have the sha-256 hash of this file, I need to generate the base64 of this hash?

What libraries do you suggest me to do that?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you thought of using CryptoJS

CryptoJS is a growing collection of standard and secure cryptographic algorithms implemented in JavaScript using best practices and patterns. They are fast, and they have a consistent and simple interface.

[CryptoJS](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/)

Basically you can include components/lib-typedarrays-min.js and then do the following in code.

```
var reader = new FileReader();

// If we use onloadend, we need to check the readyState.
reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
  if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) { // DONE == 2

    var wordArray = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(e.target.result);
    var hash = CryptoJS.SHA256(wordArray);
  }
};

var blob = file.slice(start, stop + 1);
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
```

I haven't tested the above solution but it should work fine.

Comment: Yes I've seen some example such as: var hash = CryptoJS.SHA256("Message"); but the SHA-256 method can't receive a javascript File object (given from an input type file). How can I use CryptoJS to generate a SHA-256 hash of a file?

Comment: @RobertoMilani I'll put some code regarding SHA-256 in my answer itself..!

Comment: The above code runs, but produces the wrong result. The WordArray needs to have four bytes packed into each word:
var i8a = new Uint8Array(e.target.result);
var a = [];
for (var i = 0; i < i8a.length; i += 4) {
a.push(i8a[i] << 24 | i8a[i + 1] << 16 | i8a[i + 2] << 8 | i8a[i + 3]);
}
var wordArray = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(a, i8a.length);

Comment: cliffordheath, you are right. Also a small typo above - should be evt.target.result to match the code given by CODeeerrrrrrrr.

Answer (score -5):

[OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org) is a widely used tool for cryptography